# Hadith that Narrates the Story of a Blind Man who Asked the Prophet(PBUH) about Congregational Prayer

Tags: source-identification, jamaat

The other day we were discussing the importance of Jammat(congregational) prayer. At one point, one of the guys said that a blind man came to the Prophet(PBUH) and said that he couldn't see and might not be able to attend Jammat prayer. The Prophet(PBUH) asked him if he could hear the Call for Prayer(Adhzan) and the person in question replied in the affirmative so the Prophet(PBUH) told him that as long as he could hear the sound of the Muazen, he should attend the Jammat prayer.

**Now, my question is whether the story is true. If it is, is there a Hadith that talks about this or something similar?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a well-known hadith, narrated through multiple chains.  The following is how it was narrated by Abu Hurairah, [via Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:653):

> There came to the Apostle of Allah () a blind man and said: Messenger of Allah, I have no one to guide me to the mosque. He, therefore, asked. Allah's Messenger () permission to say prayer in his house. He (tee Holy Prophet) granted him permission. Then when the man turned away he called him and said: Do you hear the call to prayer? He said: Yes. He (the Holy Prophet then) said: Respond to it.

Similar narrations have been reported from [Amr ibn Za'dah](http://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/2/162) and [Ibn Umm Maktum](http://www.sunnah.com/ibnmajah/4/58), with slightly different wording.

Comment: What does "respond to it" imply here?

Comment: @Noah Means what it sounds like, as far as I'm aware: Respond [e.g. by obeying the call].  The other two referenced ahadith don't mention the "Respond" line at all, rather they say that "I find no permission for you [to pray in your home]".

Comment: can you give me the source/hadith/volume number of Sahih muslim. a link would be great

Comment: Assalam, "respond to it" here means to respond to the call for prayer, where the muazzan says "hayyu alal sallah" meaning come unto prayer.